# Disable autosave on update in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy is autosaving the model objects when their attributes are being changed. Is there any way of disabling this and only save it when I need it?

I know there is a expunge function which detaches object model and therefore it won't be updated, but then i cannot access objects relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `autoflush` of your session to `False`:

```
session.autoflush = False
```

This way your changes will not be communicated to the database until you call

```
session.flush()
```

and will not be committed until you call

```
session.commit()
```

Further information about transaction management can be found in the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_transaction.html#)